# Method or something to run a query between 2 different databases

Tags: django

I would display some fields from a remote table according a common field (emails) between my models. I resume:

My Django project displays a main table *Prospect*, related to another table *Email* (ForeignKey). Stored in my default Django DB (Postgres).

Then I can display in another app a remote table from a third emailing tool, stored in a MySQL database, thanks to Django databases router system. All this coexists very well in my Django admin.

Now I would display in my *Prospect* admin forms some fields from my remote table, in read only of course.
In SQL/PHP, simplifying, I would do something like that:

```
SELECT myfield FROM MyRemoteTable WHERE email = {EmailValue}
```

But where and how can I do that with Django?
I think to a special method in my *Email* model, but... not easy!

**EDIT:**

As suggested by AKX, I start to add a special method in my *EmailInLine*:

```
class EmailInLine(admin.TabularInline):
model = Email
extra = 0

readonly_fields=('get_test1', )

def get_test1(self, obj):
    return "xxx"
get_test1.short_description = 'Test 1'
```

This displays "xxx" in my tabular sub-form, at right of each emails, good.

OK so now I have to find how write a Python query to recover my remote fields related, using each emails as variable in my query.

THX in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since `ModelAdmin`'s `readonly_fields` allows for callables in the admin class, you can do something like

```py
class ProspectAdmin(ModelAdmin):
  readonly_fields = (...,'external_email_info')
  #... 
  def external_email_info(self, instance: Prospect):
    return get_that_external_info(instance)
```

iirc, you can also return an html string that's been `mark_safe`d, if you need to render a widget.

Comment: Thanks, but where is done the link between the models?

Answer (score 0):

I am very proud, combining official Django doc and some syntaxes tests (...), I do exactly what I would.

Here for example, I display 2 external fields in my Email tabular forms (it means before you managed multi-DB and a Django router db, and created an app with a model from a remote table).
Then in admin.py:

```
from MyAppFromExternalDB.models import MyModelFromRemoteTable
```

...

```
class EmailInLine(admin.TabularInline):
model = Email
extra = 0

readonly_fields=('get_ExternalField1', 'get_ExternalField2')

def get_ExternalField1(self, obj):
    for temp_var in MyModelFromRemoteTable.objects.raw('SELECT subid FROM external_table WHERE email LIKE %s', [obj.email]):
        return temp_var.ExternalField1
get_ExternalField1.short_description = 'ExternalField1'

def get_ExternalField2(self, obj):
    for temp_var in MyModelFromRemoteTable.objects.raw('SELECT subid FROM external_table WHERE email LIKE %s', [obj.email]):
        return temp_var.ExternalField2
get_ExternalField2.short_description = 'ExternalField2'
```